# mysql innodb multiple index locks too many rows during query

Tags: mysql, locking, multi-index

Here is a some mysql inno_bd table `t` primary key `id` and multiple **btree** index on three fields.
Fields A, B, C is of `int`, `int`, `Date` respectively
:
[image: table]
the problem is in the following:
there is an archive `t_archive` table that I use to move the records from `t` to `t_archive` if its have already outdated. To move records I use two queries:

- `INSERT INTO t_archive SELECT * FROM t WHERE A = 1 AND B = 2 AND C = 3`
- `DELETE FROM t WHERE A = 1 AND B = 2 AND C = 3`

(As you noticed, satisfies the condition ids are 4 and 5)
During above-mentioned queries I try to `UPDATE` recods with ids : 1 and 8.
Logically, there are no reasons to `lock` records 1, 2, 3,   6, 7, 8 druring any types of queries, 
 but it happens!
Because of real red sector much more bigger than in example, transferring operations takes much time (about 50 sec) and I can't work with other recs (just UPDATE where id = 8) - getting an exception: `Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction`

Can anybody explain why it happens and how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem disappears if use more tricky `DELETE` query:

```
DELETE t FROM my_table t, 
(SELECT t1.id AS del_id  FROM my_table t1 
WHERE t1.A=1 
AND t1.B=2 
AND t1.C=3) AS del
WHERE t.id=del.del_id;
```

Comment: An explanation to what happens would be great :)

Comment: He's now using the `id` single primary key index to select the rows that needs to be deleted. My guess is that he has individual index on A, B, and C, and not composite index, so that's why too many rows were locked in the original query.

Answer (score 1):

If that is a "big" table, and if you have no suitable index, such as `INDEX(a,b,c)` (in any order), then the `DELETE` takes a long time to scan the table, hanging onto locks as it acquires them.  This risks lock-wait-timeout, or even deadlock.

If the table is "small" and/or you have a good index, does the timeout occur?

Back to the question of why `DELETE` with a subquery to get the `ids` might be less invasive:

First the `SELECT` subquery is run with minimal locks.  Then the `DELETE` is run, needing exclusive locks on at least the 2 rows in question.  If it does not time-out, I suspect it is because of the when the locks are acquires in this "2-step" version.